# How to enable CORS in OrientDb server-config.xml

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, orientdb, same-origin-policy

Am using OrientDb database, I have setup Orientdb server in my system, OrientDb has exposed Http Api's. So am trying to call API http://localhost:2480/query/test2/sql/select * from OUser , From javascript using AJAX call, I have set headers

```
Accept : "application/json;charset=utf-8",  
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",  
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTION',  
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, x-requested-with, content-type,  accept',  
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
```

And also I enabled CROS in orientdb-server-config.xml

1. parameter name="network.http.additionalResponseHeaders" value="Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*;Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept;Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTION"
2. parameter value="utf-8" name="network.http.charset"

Still am getting

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

How to enable CORS in OrientDb server?

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers, not request headers. They are used so the server can give your JS permission to read its data (not so that your JS can give itself permission to read the server's data).

You are setting them as custom request headers (in your JavaScript).

The CORS spec requires that you have explicit permission to set custom request headers, and you don't have permission from the server to set those (and why would you? They are nonsense.).

Don't set them in the JS.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I agree to the points u told. Just because am not getting response from the server I have set it up on both client (js) and server side. I have added parameters which enables CORS in orientdb-server-config.xml file. still am getting **Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response**. Any suggestions on this will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: "Just because am not getting response from the server I have set it up on both client (js) and server side." — As I said, setting it up client side is causing the problem. You are getting a response from the server. It is telling you that you are not allowed to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the client side. Stop doing that.